# Array, array, and objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I got this result in my variable

```
array(2){

  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1280 (23) 
    {
      ["num_id"]=>
      string(5) "73982"
    }
           }

  [1]=>
  array(2){
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1281 (23) 
    {
      ["num_id"]=>
    string(5) "74216"
    }

  [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#1281 (23)
    {
      ["num_id"]=>
    string(5) "74216"
    }
        
        }
          }
```

What I need is all in a single array, is that possible?
Something like ARRAY (objects of array 1, and objects of array 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this really just is about merging those entries into a single array, then the [`array_merge(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function comes in handy...

If however you need some more control, maybe want to do some sanitizing on the fly, then just iterate over the entries:

```
<?php
$input = [
  [ (object) ["num_id" => "73982" ] ],
  [ (object) ["num_id" => "74216" ] ],
  [ (object) ["num_id" => "74212" ] ]
];      

$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use(&$output) {
  $output[] = array_values($entry)[0];
});

print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [num_id] => 73982
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [num_id] => 74216
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [num_id] => 74212
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the built-in function [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Please give a actual example but just a link to a php reference.

Comment: Sure ; I've been using Php for about 15 years, from time to time, but still couldn't remember which parameter is the first in the function in_array(). Every time I'm trying to guess or to google it. But... really...  I couldn't imagine a second possible usage of self-described function array_merge... $resultArray = array_merge($array, $anotheArrayToMerge). I hope it helps ;)

Comment: That is not what the first comment asked for. Answers should not only consist of a link to an external reference here on SO. That is clearly documented. You are expected to provide an example code you wrote yourself which demonstrates the usage. That is missing from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your array is named `$a`:

```
$my_arranged_array = array_merge($a[0], ...$a[1]);
```

This will give you a plain array with objects: `[object1, object2, object3]`

Answer (score 0):

You need create a new standard class like:

```
$array_total = [];
foreach($bags as $bag){
   $items = $bag['items'];
   $array_bag = [];
   foreach($items as $item){
       $object =  new stdClass();
       $object->num_id = $item['number'];
       array_push($array_bag,$object);
       unset($object);
   }
       array_push($array_total,$array_bag);
}
```